# How to retrieve files after hard drive crash?

Tags: hard-drive, boot-failure

My hard disk was working fine. Then suddenly after moving it from another room (it is a laptop).

I did what I found suggested as I feel the HD is a now dead but?? may be I can retrieve some files?

Here's the terminal output:

```
ronald@ronald-Latitude-D505:~$ dmesg | tail
[14443.015575] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[14443.015582] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[14443.015589] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[14443.015596] Info fld=0x0
[14443.015599] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[14443.015607] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 09 07 93 10 00 00 f0 00
[14443.015622] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 151491344
[14443.015670] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 29039
[14443.015683] JBD2: recovery failed
[14443.015688] EXT4-fs (sdb1): error loading journal
ronald@ronald-Latitude-D505:~$
```

What does anyone suggest? I read this by installing a new HD and then connecting the "broken" one via a USB as an ext drive.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest booting to a live disc and see if your hard drive is at all accessible.. if it is, backup then replace the HD... If you can pull it out and set it as a secondary HD, or an external HD... You might try the [freezer "trick"](http://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux) too.... that may give you enough time to start recovering data from the HD... Other then that you can take it to a professional data recovery place and see if they can help, but that is going to be expensive...

Hope this helps, good luck!